# Semantic navigation links with titles and subtitles

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm trying to write a site using the most semantically correct HTML I can manage, and my client wants a navigation bar where each link has a title and a description/subtitle inside the clickable area. What's the best way to achieve this?

Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <a href="dashboard.html">
        <!-- There's an icon here but don't worry about that -->
        <h4>My Dashboard</h4>
        <p>Get an overview of your cases.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="new.html">
        <h4>Submit Case</h4>
        <p>Get help from the Service Center.</p>
    </a>
</nav>
```

And for reference, here's what it looks like styled:
[image: Navigation Links]

The accessibility guidelines I'm following specify that heading tags should be used in descending order (as in, `<h3>` may only appear after an `<h2>` tag, etc). The answers to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/should-menu-titles-h1-h2-h3-be-inside-or-outside-the-nav-tag) seem to indicate that it's not a good idea to use headings in the navigation regardless.

I could use `<p>` tags for both the title and description, but I'd prefer for screen-readers to be able to tell that the title is more important.

I'm inclined to use a description list, but I can't find examples where they're used this way.

Comment: you can use <p> or <div> tag also on place of <h4> and style it using CSS.

Comment: @Pushpender But would screen readers be able to tell that one is the title vs. the content? I wanna be semantic if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using styled `<p>` tags, but with a hidden colon between the title and the subtitle to still convey the hierarchy between them to screen-readers. Headings were the wrong way to go from the start, since the nav links aren't part of the page's content.